# Mac made a flash drive "read only" in Windows?

Tags: mac, usb-flash-drive, ntfs, metadata, read-only

I use a 128GB flash drive to move my work between several PCs (all win XP sp3) and a Mac with OSX 10.6. The drive is formatted as NTFS, the Mac uses the Paragon NTFS driver for read/write access. 
Here's what happened:

- Mac scanned through the whole flash drive and added its metadata to every file and directory.
- My windows computers where I am the administrator, do not see this metadata in any way.
- My windows computer in my client's office, where I do not have any admin rights, and which probably has some enhanced security imposed by IT, started to see the whole drive and all files on it as "read only".
- Any other flash drives (FAT32), which I use on that office machine allow read/write access with no problems - so this looks as some interaction of that machine's security policies with what the Mac has added.

If I simply copy the files from the affected NTFS drive to any other drive, Windows says "there is :Mac_Metadata:$DATA attached to this file, if you continue to copy, it will be lost". And when I continue to copy - the resulting copied file has no restricting attributes at all.

So the question: Why is this happening and How to tell the Mac to stop adding such metadata to flash drives?

Answer (score 1):

The `Mac_Metadata` stream should in no way prevent you from writing to the files. Streams don't work that way. It's more likely that Paragon NTFS messed up the file security (ACLs) somehow; you should be able to fix it easily by using your home PC to take ownership of all files (and reset the ACL; `cacls X:\ /t /g Everyone:F`)